# Graph automorphism edge symmetry.

Tags: graph-theory, automorphism-group

[image: Graph automorphism]

If this map just changes $2$ and $3$ is it a graph automorphism? It's not clear to me whether or not there should be an edge between $1$ and $2$ in the map's image because it isn't a geometrical symmetry, as in a horizontal flip of a rectangle, without repositioning or moving the vertices in the ambient space so the angles & lengths are unchanged.

It isn't in the graph automorphisms listed in this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X4_4Bqj6EdA&t=368s and more specifically the definition "$uv$ is an edge in $G$ iff the permutation $p(u)p(v)$ is an edge in $G$" looks like it is saying  $1,2$ is not an edge in G because $p(1)p(2) = 1,3$ is not an edge in $G$... the edge $1,2$ obviously must exist because it is in the original graph $G$ so why should the definition mean $1,2$ is not an edge?

[image: Tutorial]

Comment: There's no automorphism that exchanges $2$ and $3$, because they have different degrees.  I'm not saying that there's always an automorphism that exchanges any two vertices of the same degree, but it's a necessary condition.  Geometrical symmetries have really not much to do with this, because a graph needn't be drawn symmetrically.

Comment: Informally, if you had a physical version of this graph (made out of rubber, maybe) and threw it on the table, you would be able to tell right away which vertex was $3$: it's the part of the triangle that's not connected to anything outside the triangle. This distinguishes it from $2$ and $4$ (and therefore no automorphism will swap $2$ and $3$). On the other hand, you would know that the endpoints were $1$ and $5$, but wouldn't be able to tell which was which.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One very basic step in an automorphism is that only vertices of the same degree can be mapped to each other. So there will be no automorphism that maps $2$ to $3$ or vice versa.

The next basic step is that adjacent vertices should be mapped to adjacent vertices, etc. - this proposed swap will again fail this test as $2$ would no longer be adjacent to $1$. What you *shouldn't* do - as you appear to propose - is change the structure (the connectivity) at the same time as you change the labels.